# Why is $F[X]$ integrally closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, dedekind-domain

I am looking at the theorem that says the following:

> Let $R$ be a UFD. Then $k$ is integral over $R$ iff $k$ is algebraic over the fraction field of $R$, $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ and the minimal monic polynomial in $\mathrm{Frac}(R)[X]$ satisfied by $k$ is also in $R[X]$.

For my example of $F[X]$, let $k= \frac{1}{X}$. The fraction field of $F[X]$ is just all ratios of polynomials in $F[X]$. Now $\frac{1}{X}$ is clearly algebraic over the fraction field of $F[X]$, and the minimal monic polynomial in the fraction field satisfied by $\frac{1}{X}$ is the polynomial $T-\frac{1}{X}$ (since its monic and of degree $1$). However this polynomial is clearly not in $R[X]$.

Could someone clear things up for me? Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think you{re confusing things here: also $\;\frac12\;$ is clearly algebraic over $\;\Bbb Q[x]\;$ as a root of $\;x-\frac12\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , and yet this polynomial isn't in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ ...and, of course, $\;\frac12\;$ isn't integral over $\;\Bbb Z\;$ ... **so what** ? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Yes but in my example 1/x is indeed integral over F[X]... The theorem is that since F[X] is a UFD then its integrally closed.. Is the theorem I am quoting wrong|?

Comment: Nop, the element $\;\frac1x\;$ most certainly is not integral over $\;F[x]\;$. Why do you believe it is?

Comment: But I thought F[x] was integrally closed?

Comment: and 1/x is in its fraction field..

Comment: Yes, it is...so what?

Comment: Also $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is int. closed and $\;\frac12\;$ is in its fraction field! What are you trying to claim?? I just don't understand you...

Comment: Doesn't R integrally closed mean the integral closure of R= Frac(R)?

Comment: Oh it actually means integral closure of R= R ? Sorry!

Comment: Now I see what annoying confussion you had. An integral domain $\;A\;$ is called *integrally closed* if the integral closure of $\;A\;$ in its field of fractions is $\;A\;$ itself...! It does **not** mean its field of fractions is the integral closure of $\;A\;$ in that field...!

Comment: Thank you so much DonAntonio!